# How to validate if ical ( iCalendar ) file is valid using javascript?

Tags: javascript, icalendar

Is there any javascript library which I can use to validate if ical file is valid.

Below is invalid ical file content example

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
END:VCALENDAR
```

Looks like https://github.com/mozilla-comm/ical.js/ is not useful. Unable to invalidate above ical file.

There is no event. This is also failing with icalendar.org/validator.html ( would like to see something like this )

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use server-side validation by https://icalendar.org/validator.html
They have an option to show errors in JSON format from ical feed from URL

`https://icalendar.org/validator.html?url=https://example.com/somecalendar_feed&json=1`