# Validate a Recurrence rule string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rrule

I receive a  `RecurrenceRule` as a string from a Post request, I need to validate that the rule is a valid format.

The string I receive is something like this:

`DTSTART:20200420T050000Z RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH;INTERVAL=1`

How can I validate that this string is correct, is there a way to do it like this?:

```
rruleVariable.tryParse("DTSTART:20200420T050000Z RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH;INTERVAL=1")
```

I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: What defines a valid string?

Comment: Recurrence Rule is a standard for events that have recurrence
You can check that here https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-5-3-recurrence-rule.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with icalendar, but the validation rules look pretty complex. I wouldn't reinvent the wheel, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633682/1048799 which points to https://icalendar.org/validator.html. Also, have you checked NuGet for a package that does this?

Comment: I found one called rrule-parser.net I'll see If this is what I need

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help, I need to pay closer attention to tags.

Comment: Just to update you, rrule-parser.net did help me.

Here is a link to the project: https://github.com/Deep-Winter/rrule-parser.net

PS: your comment was actually helpful, thanks

Comment: Great! I think it would a good idea to post your solution with some example code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this using rrule-parser.net

I needed to validate the rrule format so I used the ParseRRule function like this

```
var ruleParser = RRuleParser.CreateDefault();

            try
                {
                    string parseRrule = ruleParser.ParseRRule(FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH;INTERVAL=1);
/*this outputs to human readable text and in case it can't parse
 it means that the Rrule string is not valid*/
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    //returns error message
                }
```